# how to return an object without using await

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am not an async gal nor an expert node.js programmer.

I cannot figure out how to return the newly added record that I am posting.

```
  person.POST(personObject).then(
    (result) => {
      console.log('Result', result); //undefined
      res.send(result)
    },
    (error) => {
      log.error(error, error.message);
      res.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }); 
    })
```

POST:

```
module.exports = async (aPerson) => {
  Person.create(aPerson)
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err
  })
  .then((newPerson) => {
    console.log('newPerson: ',newPerson); //this has a value
    return newPerson;
  })

  //works but does this kill the advantage of async???
  // const result = await Person.create(aPerson);
  // return result;
};
```

newPerson is the newly created record via sequalize.

Gina

Comment: Could You Please Clarify your question?

Comment: Place a `return` in front of `Person.create`.  Also, I would say the commented out section is preferred (more readable).

Comment: Async is async all the way down.  You can't return an async value and not wait for it to resolve.  Anything that depends on an asynchronous value becomes asynchronous.  Additionally, it's not very clear where you are having issues.  Is it that you don't want to use the `Promise`?  Additionally, your "POST" as you have it now, does not return anything because it does not return the Promise that `Person.create(aPerson)` would hypothetically return.

Comment: The commented out section is also functionally equivalent to what you have with the addition of a `return` statement.

Comment: I want to use the return value in "res.send(result)", I have the value in the then but I do not have the value for use in the res.send.

Comment: @c1moore you were correct. I could have sworn I tried that. Can you post your answer.

Comment: I really wish a comment were required for down votes.

Comment: @zero298 I think you were telling me the same thing as c1moore. Thx as well.

Comment: @GinaMarano I've posted an answer.  Let me know if that helps clarify what `async`/`await` is.  If that doesn't help, I have another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680055/difference-between-serial-and-parallel/50680958#50680958) that goes into much more detail with example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, the issue with your code was you weren't returning the Promise.  To fix that, all you have to do is return the Promise.  That would look something like

```js
module.exports = (aPerson) => {
  return Person.create(aPerson)
  // Catch isn't necessary, but I'm adding it to show the async/await equivalent.
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err
  });
};
```

There seems to be some confusion around `async`/`await`, though, so I wanted to clarify a few things.  The above function is the same exact thing as

```js
module.exports = async (aPerson) => {
  try {
    return await Person.create(aPerson);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

`async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for Promises.  It helps make code readable.  If you plug either of the snippets above into your code, they will both function the same.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your POST function isn't returning a `Promise` that will resolve with your result. Since there is no `return` statement in your function, it will return a simple `Promise.resolve()` as it exits because of the `async` declaration, but that isn't what you want.  You want to return an actual `Promise` whose `resolve` will have the data.  Here's an implementation that illustrates it:

```
module.exports = (aPerson) => {    // <-- no async neeeded
  return Person.create(aPerson)    // <-- return the Promise here
  .then((newPerson) => {
    console.log('newPerson: ',newPerson); //this has a value
    return newPerson;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  })
};
```

Note a couple of things:

- the function no longer has `async`. That's only needed if you want to use `await` in your function, which you don't do.
- the function now returns the `Promise` that `Person.create().then()` returns.

Also I moved the `.catch` to the end of the `.chain` since it will be jumped to if any part of the chain throws an exception or returns an unhandled rejection. Here the `.catch` doesn't do anything but re-throw, so isn't really needed, but in case you wanted to do something with the error, you could.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but c1moore answered first in comment.